# How to use lenient mode with FasterXML CBOR?

Tags: java, utf-8, jackson, fasterxml, cbor

I want to use the [`CBORGenerator.Feature.LENIENT_UTF_ENCODING` enum](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/blob/3f09c477a6a6f83d17fd99da61f6649dbd48cf17/cbor/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/cbor/CBORGenerator.java#L79-L90) that was introduced in version 2.12 of the [jackson-dataformats-binary](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary) library. I am using version 2.16.0 of the library.

I thought I could do something like this:

```java
CBORMapper.builder()
    .enable(CBORGenerator.Feature.LENIENT_UTF_ENCODING)
    .build();
```

but this gives me this error:

```
error: no suitable method found for enable(com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.Feature)
              .enable(CBORGenerator.Feature.LENIENT_UTF_ENCODING)
              ^
```

I tried using `.configure(CBORGenerator.Feature.LENIENT_UTF_ENCODING, true)` instead, but then I get this error:

```
error: no suitable method found for configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORGenerator.Feature,boolean)
              .configure(CBORGenerator.Feature.LENIENT_UTF_ENCODING, true)
              ^
```

How can I correctly create a `CBORMapper` instance for CBOR decoding with `LENIENT_UTF_ENCODING` enabled?